# Targets for calculating camera pose

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Using OpenCV SolvePnP I want to determine the pose of a (calibrated) camera. I know that I need at least 4 points to solve for the 6 degrees of freedom of the camera pose. I'm trying to determine the requirements for my target. If I have a field of view of say 200 mm, is there an optimal distance between these four points on my target?
I want to be able to detect small changes in camera pose, e.g. a rotation of say 1 degree.
It would seem intuitively that having these four points farther apart would be preferable, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can determine the requirements for this four point target.

Comment: just wallpaper your room with "ChArUco" boards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just placed an order for 500 sq ft ;)

Comment: not kidding (mostly). your task appears to be (parts of) Augmented Reality, namely positioning. I don't know if you know how to find those points you spoke of. in any case, why make your life harder, why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was trying to understand the method of SolvePnP a bit better. I know I need at least 4 points, I know if I have a four point target with precisely known locations that will result in a better estimate of pose. Intuitively it seems that having these four points farther apart would be preferable if nothing more than it would make it easier to detect small angular pose changes.

Comment: Assuming accuracy of your camera intrinsic parameter is perfect, only error of detected point position will cause error of pose estimation result.
I don't know how to evaluate the impact... but, it may be possible to think simulation (Monte Carlo estimation ?), I think.

Comment: (This may not be relevant to this question...) In my experience, it was very difficult to distinguish between small rotation and small translation.
In your case, this confusion can be a problem because you are dealing with small rotations.
Estimating rotation and translation separately (rather than at same time) may avoid confusion, I think.
Only using eroughly far points (can be assumed as infinite), you can estimate camera rotation only. And then, estimate camera translation if needed.